# null values is not taking in insert query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

**DistrictMaster** :

```
-----------------------------------------------------
DistrictID     |        DistrictName   |    State
-----------------------------------------------------
    21         |          ABC          |    ktm
    22         |          XYZ          |    ktm
    32         |          PQR          |    johar
-----------------------------------------------------
```

**Districtdetail**:

```
District      |   DistrciID  | State   | Country  
------------------------------------------------
PQR           |              | johar   |   MY
null          |              | Kedah   |   MY
ABC           |              | ktm     |   MY
              |              | Kedah   |   MY
XYZ           |              | ktm     |   MY
------------------------------------------------
```

I need to insert `DistrictID` in `Districtdetail` which have few null and no values.I used below query but its not inserting.

```
insert into Districtdetail(DistrictID)
    select 
        a.id  
    from 
        DistrictMaster a 
    left join 
        Districtdetail b on a.DistrictName = b.DistrictName 
                         and a.State = b.State;
```

Above query is saying executed but nothing is inserted.

Comment: `insert` is used to create *new* rows. I suspect that you want to update *existing* rows, so you should be looking at `update` instead.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever can I use join in update table ?

Comment: In SQL Server you can use a join in an UPDATE. This is non-standard, though, and may not translate to other database systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simple update statement with join:

```
update d
set DistrictID = m.DistrictID
from DistrictMaster m
join Districtdetail d on m.DistrictName = d.District and m.State = d.State
```

Comment: Its saying 0 rows affected

Comment: It means you have no related data in those tables...Or you have some spaces in data or hidden symbols like new line or tab...

Answer (score 0):

You could have troubles doing a join update if primary keys are not preserved in the join.
In that case, you should try updating `Districtdetail` this way:

```
update Districtdetail dd
set dd.DistrictID = (select dm.DistrictID 
                       from DistrictMaster dm
                      where dm.DistrictName = dd.District
                        and dm.State = dd.State)
where exists
(select * 
   from DistrictMaster dm
  where dm.DistrictName = dd.District
    and dm.State = dd.State)
```